# cannot get lineitems to work in Authorized.net xml createTransactionRequest

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am trying to take info out of a mysql table and insert it into the createTransactionRequest array to show the lineitems in the email. When I do this and echo it on on the page it looks like it should but it keeps giving me an error. If I remove the array ( $lineitem ) I create it goes through fine. I feel I am inserting this wrong or its just not possible to do this the way I am trying to do it. Hoping someone with more experience in this can help me figure it out.

I create the array like this.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($cartitems)) {
$lineitem[] = array('itemId' => ''.$r['itemid'].'','name' => ''.$r['productname'].'','description' => ''.$r['productdescription'].'','quantity' => '1','unitPrice' => ''.$price.'');
}
```

Then I plug it into the array like this..

```
$xml->createTransactionRequest(array(
'refId' => rand(1000000, 100000000),
'transactionRequest' => array(
'transactionType' => 'authCaptureTransaction',
'amount' => 45.00,
'payment' => array(
'creditCard' => array(
    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111',
    'expirationDate' => '122015',
    'cardCode' => '123',
),
),
'order' => array(
'invoiceNumber' => '123123',
'description' => 'Purchase from website',
),
'lineItems' => array(
'lineItem' => $lineitem
),
'poNumber' => '123123321',
'customer' => array(
'id' => 123,
'email' => email@website.com,
),
'billTo' => array(
'firstName' => $firstname,
'lastName' => $lastname,
'address' => $address,
'city' => $city,
'state' => $state,
'zip' => $zipcode,
'country' => 'USA',
),
'customerIP' => 12-12-12-1234,
'transactionSettings' => array(
'setting' => array(
    0 => array(
        'settingName' =>'allowPartialAuth',
        'settingValue' => 'false'
                                                ),
    1 => array(
        'settingName' => 'duplicateWindow',
        'settingValue' => '0'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'settingName' => 'emailCustomer',
        'settingValue' => 'true'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'settingName' => 'recurringBilling',
        'settingValue' => 'false'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'settingName' => 'testRequest',
        'settingValue' => 'false'
    )
)
),
),
));
```

---------------editing below, showing output from print----------------

```
Array
(
    [refId] => 90801855
    [transactionRequest] => Array
        (
            [transactionType] => authCaptureTransaction
            [amount] => 31.41
            [payment] => Array
                (
                    [creditCard] => Array
                        (
                            [cardNumber] => 4111111111111111
                            [expirationDate] => 042012
                            [cardCode] => 123
                        )

                )

            [order] => Array
                (
                    [invoiceNumber] => 1360116011
                    [description] => Purchase from website
                )

            [lineItems] => Array
                (
                    [lineItem] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [itemId] => 1
                                    [name] => item one title
                                    [description] => item one description
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [unitPrice] => 19.90
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [itemId] => 4
                                    [name] => item 4 title
                                    [description] => item 4 description
--
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [unitPrice] => 15.00
                                )

                        )

                )

            [poNumber] => 22
            [customer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [email] => email@website.com
                )

            [billTo] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => john
                    [lastName] => smith
                    [address] => 132 addy here lane
                    [city] => foxboro
                    [state] => MA
                    [zip] => 01955
                    [country] => USA
                )

            [customerIP] => 12.123.123.123
            [transactionSettings] => Array
                (
                    [setting] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [settingName] => allowPartialAuth
                                    [settingValue] => false
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [settingName] => duplicateWindow
                                    [settingValue] => 0
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [settingName] => emailCustomer
                                    [settingValue] => true
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [settingName] => recurringBilling
                                    [settingValue] => false
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [settingName] => testRequest
                                    [settingValue] => false
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, Scott. I'm the author of the library you're using. Can you do me a favor and do a `print_r($lineitem)` for me so I can see the output?

Comment: @JohnConde all set. I edited above. I put it in a pre tag. If you prefer it without the pre wrap let me know and I can paste that in instead. Thanks you very much for taking a look.

Comment: I'm going to use this info and see if I can duplicate it over here. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good news, or bad news. I was able to get my two tests to work using the data you provided.

- [Code Example 1](http://pastebin.com/z5YxUew1)
- [Code Example 2](http://pastebin.com/fLkGbZEU)
- [Results](http://pastebin.com/WH6b4uKM)

The first code example was using my sample code with the data you provided. The sample code is using the code you provided above with the line items manually added by me. You can see the request and response XML in the third code sample.

While we work through this here's some tips that may be useful:

- In your sample data provided above, in the second line item I saw a couple of dashes `--` randomly in there. Are they in your code? Or was that just a cut & paste error?
- Authorize.Net doesn't really care if numeric values are passed in quotes so putting them in there is always a good idea.

Comment: John its the oddest thing. If I drop in the output ( and add in a comma to separate the arrays in lineitem ) it works fine but if I create that array from the mysql output then drop that array variable in it doesnt work. The only difference is adding in that comma. Were you able to get this to work by creating lineitem array from a loop then dropping the variable in?